# Gearman and inotify for tasks execution

Tags: php, gearman, inotify, php-5.5

I have some doubts in how i can efficiently use gearman in my php application.

Im using inotify for monitoring a folder where a lot of files will be stored and processed (more than 1000 per time). 
For parsing each of them and save it's content in a database im trying to use gearman.

```
    while(true){
        sleep(5);   # spare some CPU Cycles
        set_time_limit(0); # unlimited timeout request 
        // read events 
        $events = inotify_read($this->instance);

        // if the event is happening within our 'Files directory'
            if ($events[0]['wd'] === $this->watch_id){              
                foreach ($events as $key=>$value)
                {
                    if($events[$key]['mask'] === IN_CREATE){
                        # A new file was created in folder                          
                        $client = new \GearmanClient();
                        $client->addServer();
                        $client->addTask("parse_file", $events[$key]['name']);  # add task to parse that file
                        printf("Created file: %s in Files directory\n", $events[$key]['name']);
                    }
                    else if ($events[$key]['mask'] === IN_DELETE){
                        printf("Deleted file: %s in Files directory\n", $events[$key]['name']);
                    }                           
                }
                if(!is_null($client)){  # once everything is done, run the tasks.   
                    $client->runTasks();                
                }
            }
    }
```

I created a worker.php file like this:

```
<?php
namespace controllers;
use app\file\File;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$worker = new \GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction('parse_file', function($job){
    echo "entrou no add function!<br>";
    print_r ($job->workload());
    sleep(2);
    return new File($job->workload()); # this class parses the files content in database
});                     
while ($worker->work());
```

Things are happening now. The worker function runs and the data of the first file is stored in the the database but a error occurs:

This is the output of my nohup.out file.

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class app\file\File could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/worker.php on line 18
```

What does "he" want? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to figure it out the final piece of the problem.

The error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class app\file\File could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/worker.php on line 18
```

Was because i was returning a object here:

```
sleep(2);
    return new File($job->workload()); # this class parses the files content in database
```

Not returning anything in my worker function happened to fix the error. Need to study better Gearman and how to create more workers to run my code.

**Just for the record:** If you try to connect a worker to a remote gearman job server, you will probably have a bad time. 
To allow remote connections you must change the listen port in gearman-server configuration located at `/etc/default/gearman-job-server`:

```
# Parameters to pass to gearmand.
PARAMS=""
```

Beware that this way the server is completely open to remote connections from anywhere if you have it in a public network.